# W: Target Translations

Tags: apt, upgrade

I was sent here with my question because I am running Linux Mint Mate and askubuntu does not support help with my operating system so hopefully someone here can help. If this question has already been posted I apologize and will happily take it down.

My sources lists don't seem to have anything in them when I open them so I don't know where it is getting this multiple locations from.

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com sarah InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com sarah Release                              
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease               
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease             
Fetched 94.5 kB in 1s (74.0 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

I tried the python solution and nothing happened.

`sources.list` contains

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###

# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` contains

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` contains

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: delete one of similar lines.

Comment: I would if I knew how, I'll admit that I'm still new to some aspect of the linux system

Comment: With any text editor.
Or just simply ignore this warning message.

Comment: like i stated in my question, when i open the sources.list there is nothing there at all, unless the list is hidden and im not finding the right one

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` ?

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list: Permission denied
`

Comment: You can't *run* them; try `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`.

Comment: Lol, seems I need to find myself a doc of commands. I'll give that a try

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

          `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings tell you where the duplicates are:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

You need to look at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`. They both define the same repositories, but the former is better because it specifies that the repository is `amd64`-only; you should remove `google.list`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this terminal command

```
sudo apt install python3-apt
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidfoerster/apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries/master/apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
chmod +x apt-remove-duplicate-source-entries.py
```

Comment: Why would I do something complicated like you are suggesting, when a simple one liner will help?

Answer (score -1):

Extending [Stephen Kitt's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315841/208146) answer, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```